# setting the height of a SELECT in jelly beans

Tags: android, html, css, uiwebview, webkit

i'm using the webview and the select item's height is smaller than expected in jelly bean .
it works perfectly in ics !!.how do i make it appear properly??

```
#select{

    background:url('images/select-box.png') no-repeat;
    width:352px;
    height:84px;
    border: 0;
}
```